# Imported python submodule cannot import sibling submodule, No Module named

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc-python

I
have a python project with the following code/directory structure:

```
main.py
pb/
  pb_pb2_grpc.py
  pb_pb2.py
```

```
// main.py
from pb.pb_pb2_grpc import add_DesignOutputServiceServicer_to_server
```

```
//pb_pb2_grpc.py
import pb_pb2 as pb__pb2
```

Running `main.py` gives me the following error:

```
python3.7 -m main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pb.pb_pb2_grpc import add_DesignOutputServiceServicer_to_server
  File "/pb/pb_pb2_grpc.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pb_pb2 as pb__pb2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pb_pb2'
```

How can I get this submodule to import its sibling correctly? `pb_pb2_grpc.py` and `pb_pb2.py` are both generated code and cannot be modified.

Comment: Are those protocol buffers? The best approach here is probably to change how you're generating your generated code.

Comment: Yes, these are protocol buffers, generated using [grpcio-tools](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-tools/). They don't offer much in the way of changing generated code, only configuring input files, and output directory/files

`$ python -m grpc.tools.protoc -I$INCLUDE --python_out=$OUTPUT --grpc_python_out=$OUTPUT $PROTO_FILES`